# Order of EMR Steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

When initially setting up a new EMR cluster, and you add steps to your cluster, the order that they append to the page is top-down, meaning the top entry runs first, the bottom entry runs last.

When you are watching the progress of those steps in a running EMR cluster, they run bottom-up, meaning bottom runs first, top runs last.

When I export a CLI command for the setup of the cluster, and run that via DataPipeline, it contains the --steps flag which has an array of steps, the first-running step is last item in the array.

Needless to say, it is very confusing to me how I would actually mandate the order of particular steps for the ETL job I'm doing.

**Is there a way to explicitly specify the order of these steps?**

Comment: Looks like its a bug, I manually wrote down the steps [1,2,3], they ran in the expected order i.e 1 followed by 2 followed by 3. But when I exported the CLI for the emr run. In the exported emr create command they were present in reverse order and executing it caused the steps to be executed in reverse order. Initially I thought ordering in UI is causing this as in UI you can sort the steps, but its not the case, sorting in UI does not affect the order. CLI export always exports the step in reverse order in which they were executed

Answer (score 5):

They do run in the order you specify them via the API, but for some reason the web console has weird sorting when displaying them.